# Update UI from GCM Service Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, service

I have a fragment that has a `list`. I want to insert a new row every time a GCM notification comes.

**PART 1**

I am confused at where I should attach the array adapter:

```
listView.setAdapter(user_adapter); //this code
```

1. in my fragment
2. in GCM Service

If I choose implementing it in GCM service, how can I get the reference of the layout that is inflated in my fragment?

**My Code**

```
ArrayList<Add_Friend> array_of_friends = new ArrayList<Add_Friend>();
    User_Adapter user_adapter = new User_Adapter(getContext(),1,array_of_friends);
    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_1);
    listView.setAdapter(user_adapter);
```

**Code Written for Service**

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
Update_Friend_Req_List update_friend_req_list;

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    Log.d(TAG, "DATA: " + data);
    //Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    String senders_email = data.getString("senders_email");

    if(message.equals("New Friend Req")){
        //Use Array Adapter to make friends list
        //Use a broadcast receiver to update list
        //register_broadcast_update_friend_req();

        //Directly update UI

    }

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }


}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for your service?

Comment: i have shown the code for service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to access the layout directly, but there are a few ways you could approach this. I think the cleanest way to do this is to setup a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your Fragment which you register and deregister on the fragment's lifecycle. In your service, you then broadcast a custom Intent, possibly containing the new data, preferably using `LocalBroadcastManager` to keep all the broadcasts internal. That way, you have your fragment listening for messages using the receiver, and only while the fragment is active.

If you actually want to start a certain view if it isn't running when you receive a message, you'll need to do something with `startActivity` from within your Service.